# JBOSS Driver named "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" is not installed

Tags: java, jboss, mariadb, ejbca

Install MariaDB Java connector in JBOSS7

I have trouble to deploy EJBCA 6 on JBOSS7 with MariaDB. I have configured EJBCA to use JBOSS standalone. My configuration works when using the default H2 database backend. I have configured mariadb Java connector in the JBOSS standalone.xml

```
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mariadb" module="org.mariadb.jdbc">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>

            <datasource jndi-name="java:/MariaDS" pool-name="MariaDS" enabled="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/ejbca</connection-url>
                <driver>mariadb</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements/>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
        </datasources>
```

and I have copied the MariaDB Java connector to JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/mariadb/jdbc/main/mariadb-java-client-1.1.5.jar and configured the module.xml like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.mariadb.jdbc">
      <resources>
        <resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-1.1.5.jar"/>
      </resources>
      <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
      </dependencies>
    </module>
```

the MariaDB driver is listed in the boot.log and server.log. It is also listed via jboss-cli:

```
    [standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=datasources:installed-drivers-list
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => [
            {
                "driver-name" => "mariadb",
                "deployment-name" => undefined,
                "driver-module-name" => "org.mariadb.jdbc",
                "module-slot" => "main",
                "driver-datasource-class-name" => "",
                "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" =>         "org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource",
                "driver-class-name" => "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
                "driver-major-version" => 1,
                "driver-minor-version" => 1,
                "jdbc-compliant" => false
            },
            {
                "driver-name" => "h2",
                "deployment-name" => undefined,
                "driver-module-name" => "com.h2database.h2",
                "module-slot" => "main",
                "driver-datasource-class-name" => "",
                "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" => "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",
                "driver-class-name" => "org.h2.Driver",
                "driver-major-version" => 1,
                "driver-minor-version" => 3,
                "jdbc-compliant" => true
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have set the EJBCA database.properties like this:

```
    database.driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    database.url=jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/ejbca?characterEncoding=UTF
    database.name=mysql
```

however when I try to deploy EJBCA to the JBOSS with ant deploy the deployment fails with:

```
    jee:deployDSJBoss7:
         [exec] Result: 1
         [exec] Result: 1
         [echo] data-source add --name=ejbcads --driver-name="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" --connection-url="jdbc:mysql://ejbca-test-05.vm:3306/ejbca?characterEncoding=UTF-8" --jndi-name="java:/EjbcaDS"  --use-ccm=true --user-name="ejbca" --password="reverse" --validate-on-match=true --background-validation=false --prepared-statements-cache-size=50 --share-prepared-statements=true --min-pool-size=5 --max-pool-size=150 --pool-prefill=true --transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED --check-valid-connection-sql="select 1"
         [exec] JBAS010468: Driver named "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" is not installed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding it from the UI rather than going through config files. It would be easier and less error prone.

Comment: thanks. But using the ui is not an option for me as I'm deploying EJBCA via Ansible. Anyway I think I found a solution to my problem. It seems like running ant deploy again solves the error. But I'm still debugging this.

Comment: If you are havin trouble to install EJBCA with JBOSS and MariaDB you can take a look at my Ansible role: https://github.com/knowhy/ansible-role-ejbca

Comment: Thank you very much, Henrick for the github link. You made my life easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Copy module.xml and mariadb-java-client.jar in jboss modules base dir ...\org\mariadb\main\
2. Refer to the below sample for module.xml. Update the jar file name with yours

   ```
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.mariadb">
       <resources>
           <resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-1.3.3.jar"/>
       </resources>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="javax.api"/>
           <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
       </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```
3. Refer to the below for Datasource config in standalone.xml or the xml you use. Replace IP/hostname, port no, database name(DB1), poolname, jndi-name as per what you need.

   ```
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MariaDBDS" pool-name="MariaDBDS" enabled="true" statistics-enabled="true">
       <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://10.92.142.148:6603/DB1</connection-url>
       <driver>mariadb</driver>
       <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>
       <security>
           <user-name>your-database-username</user-name>
           <password>password</password>
       </security>
       <validation>
           <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
           <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
           <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
       </validation>
   </datasource>
   ```

Comeback to this part later and update your connection pool

4. Add below in drivers

   ```
   <driver name="mariadb" module="org.mariadb">
       <xa-datasource-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
   </driver>
   ```
5. Start jboss and check datasources in the console and test connection

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of strange things:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/MariaDS" pool-name="MariaDS" enabled="false">
```

the enabled=false should not be there or true like:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
```

also it is common to have the datasource elements and then the drivers elements.

Answer (score 0):

For me below worked after seraching  a lot and collectiong bits and pieces

First need to deploy Mariadb jar file through jboss-cli, then add module to under org/mariadb/main/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.mariadb">  <resources>   <resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar"/></resources>  <dependencies>   <module name="javax.api"/>   <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>   </dependencies> </module>
```

then add changes in standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/MariaDBDS" pool-name="MariaDBDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/DbName</connection-url>
                <driver>mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar</driver>
                <driver-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                
                <security>
                    <user-name>uname</user-name>
                    <password>pwd</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```